# Unexplained bad access error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I have some code where I iterate through an array. I am adding a second mutable array so that I can add objects to it, which I wish to remove after the iteration is complete. This however is causing bad access errors when I attempt to add the object to the second array I created. This is confusing me, because the object I am trying to add can be used for all types of things, just not adding to this array. This lead me to believe that maybe the array was getting released, so I retained it, but that had no effect. Here is the code:

```
    CCTMXObjectGroup *objectGroup = [ self objectGroupNamed: @"object" ];
    NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [ NSMutableArray array ];
    for ( NSDictionary *object in [ objectGroup objects ] ) {
        [ objectsToRemove addObject: object ]; // crash occurs here
        // name, type, x, y, width, height
        NSString *name = [ object valueForKey: @"name" ];
        if ( [ name isEqualToString: @"sprite" ] ) {
            [ self createSpriteFromObject: object ];
        } else if ( [ name isEqualToString: @"spriteController" ] ) {
            [ self createSpriteControllerFromObject: object ];
        }
    }
```

If I remove the addObject line, the crash will no longer occur. Here is the kicker, the crash only seems to occur on the 6th iteration. Stepping through the code, the mutable array I am adding to, and the object that I am adding to it both seem to be fine (not released). Why the bad access error then?

**Edit**

```
CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM addObject:]:
0x23c39e0:  pushl  %ebp
0x23c39e1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x23c39e3:  pushl  %edi
0x23c39e4:  pushl  %esi
0x23c39e5:  subl   $16, %esp
0x23c39e8:  calll  0x23c39ed                 ; -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 13
0x23c39ed:  popl   %edi
0x23c39ee:  movl   1512267(%edi), %eax
0x23c39f4:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x23c39f8:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0x23c39fb:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
0x23c39fe:  calll  0x24e35c8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x23c3a03:  movl   1512287(%edi), %ecx
0x23c3a09:  movl   %eax, 12(%esp)
0x23c3a0d:  movl   16(%ebp), %eax
0x23c3a10:  movl   %eax, 8(%esp)
0x23c3a14:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x23c3a18:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
0x23c3a1b:  calll  0x24e35c8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x23c3a20:  addl   $16, %esp ; bad access code 2
0x23c3a23:  popl   %esi
0x23c3a24:  popl   %edi
0x23c3a25:  popl   %ebp
0x23c3a26:  ret    
0x23c3a27:  nopw   (%eax,%eax)
```

and

```
libsystem_sim_c.dylib`bzero$VARIANT$sse42:
0x1f9c200:  pushl  %ebp
0x1f9c201:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1f9c203:  pushl  %edi
0x1f9c204:  movl   8(%ebp), %edi
0x1f9c207:  movl   12(%ebp), %edx
0x1f9c20a:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x1f9c20c:  cmpl   $80, %edx
0x1f9c20f:  jg     0x1f9c24c                 ; bzero$VARIANT$sse42 + 76
0x1f9c211:  cmpl   $12, %edx
0x1f9c214:  jge    0x1f9c226                 ; bzero$VARIANT$sse42 + 38
0x1f9c216:  testl  %edx, %edx
0x1f9c218:  je     0x1f9c246                 ; bzero$VARIANT$sse42 + 70
0x1f9c21a:  movb   %al, (%edi) ; bad access code 2
0x1f9c21c:  incl   %edi
```

Comment: You say "unexplained", but I guarantee you there is a stacktrace and crash log. Please post them.

Comment: @sosborn bear with me, I am only about a month old when it comes to objective-c. I see nothing in the output logger. The stack trace that appears leads from the line I mentioned in the original post as being the problem, to some weird assembly looking internals that I don't really understand. I have posted these in an edit to the above post, and commented the lines that get the bad access.

Comment: What does the objectGroupNamed: method look like?

Comment: @nickfalk objectGroupNamed is from cocos2d-iphone, which is a widely used framework. I would like to think that the bug is not there, but it's starting to look like it may be.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [ NSMutableArray array ];
for ( NSDictionary *object in [ objectGroup objects ] ) {
    [ objectsToRemove addObject: object ]; // crash occurs here
```

If the crash is occurring there, then it can't have anything to do with `objectsToRemove` (unless there is code you haven't shown).

It means that the `object` is bunko.  Likely, it has been released out from under `objectGroup`.  Turn on Zombie detection and re-run your app.

Note: It can be daunting to debug this stuff when you are new.  Some tips:

• If you are staring at assembly code, you are almost assuredly off in the weeds.

• If you are crashing in a Foundation framework method, it is pretty much guaranteed the bug is elsewhere because those methods get executed hundreds of millions of time to boot your Mac or your iOS device.  Assuming they work is a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue lay with the NSMutableArray initialization. I was using:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [ NSMutableArray array ];
```

When it should have been:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 10 ];
```

Comment: This seems highly unlikely. `arrayWithCapacity:` has just some minor performance benefits over `array` when you know how many objects your array will contain. It should *not* cause different behavior in any way.